# Capture money longer than 29 days in PayPal

Tags: paypal, payment

Is there way how to capture/hold money longer then 29 days in PayPal?

The original problem is I have to capture money for some specified duration that can be longer that 29 days. If some happens (project's business logic) a captured money will be released without any tax. Is it possible to implement it with PayPal?

Thanks in advance.

-Viktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately by default PayPal honors 100% of authorized funds for only upto 3 days. You could use it from 4 - 29 days but you would have to reauth before you can capture. More information here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_admin_authcapture

Answer (score 1):

You could look at delayed chained payments. ( https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/how-to-guides/how-make-delayed-chained-payment-using-adaptive-payments )

Chained payments involves two receivers: A primary and a secondary. The money moves from sender, to primary, and then a portion (up to 100%) of the payment moves from primary to secondary.   You can delay that second transfer for up to 90 days, giving you a chance to verify that your conditions are met before releasing the money to the secondary receiver.

However it comes with two drawbacks.
1) The money is actually charged to the user from the start, and is held by the primary receiver.  If you need to do a full refund, overall you will lose $0.30
2) The primary receiver is liable for the transaction. If the buyer decides to open a claim and wins, the primary is on the hook.

So yes, it is possible, but caveat emptor :)